# Scrapy Spider following urls, but wont export the data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to grab details from a real estate listing page. I can grab all the data, I just can't seem to export it..

Perhaps a problem with the way I use the `yield` keyword. The code work for the most part:

- Visits page 1, example.com/kittens
- Goes to page 2, example.com/puppers. Here are 10 apartments listed in blocks. I can get data from each block, but I need additional info from inside the hyperlink.
- Visits the hyperlink, say, example.com/puppers/apartment1. It grabs some info from here as well, but I can't seem to return this data to include it in my `HousingItem()` class.

  ```
  import scrapy
  from urllib.parse import urljoin

  class HousingItem(scrapy.Item):
       street      = scrapy.Field()
       postal      = scrapy.Field()
       city        = scrapy.Field()
       url         = scrapy.Field()

       buildY         = scrapy.Field()
       on_m           = scrapy.Field()
       off_m          = scrapy.Field()


  class FAppSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'f_app'
      allowed_domains = ['example.com']
      start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/kittens']

      def parse(self, response):

           yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.example.com/puppers",
               callback=self.parse_puppers)   

      def parse_inside_pupper(self, response):

           item = HousingItem()
           item['buildY']          = response.xpath('').extract_first().strip()
           item['on_m']            = response.xpath('').extract_first().strip()
           item['off_m']           = response.xpath('').extract_first().strip()


      def parse_puppers(self, response):

           base_url = 'https://www.example.com/'
           for block in response.css('div.search-result-main'):

                item = HousingItem()
                item['street']          = block.css(''),
                item['postcode']        = block.css(''),
                item['city']            = block.css('')
                item['url']             = urljoin(base_url, block.css('div.search-result-header > a::attr(href)')[0].extract())

              # Problem area from here.. 

                yield response.follow(url=item['url'],callback=self.parse_inside_pupper)

              # yield scrapy.request(url=item['url'],callback=self.parse_inside_pupper)?

                yield item
  ```

`FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` is adjusted in my `SETTINGS.py`. The 4 items from `parse_puppers()` get exported correctly, `parse_inside_puppers()` data is correct in the console, but wont export.

I use `scrapy crawl f_app -o raw_data.csv` to run me spider. Thanks in advance, appreciate all the help.

p.s. im fairly new to python and practising, i bet you noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send you current `item` to the `parse_inside_pupper` using `meta` param:

```
def parse_puppers(self, response):

     base_url = 'https://www.example.com/'
     for block in response.css('div.search-result-main'):

          item = HousingItem()
          item['street']          = block.css(''),
          item['postcode']        = block.css(''),
          item['city']            = block.css('')
          item['url']             = urljoin(base_url, block.css('div.search-result-header > a::attr(href)')[0].extract())

          yield response.follow(url=item['url'],callback=self.parse_inside_pupper, meta={"item": item})
```

After that you can use it inside parse_inside_pupper (and `yield` it from here):

```
def parse_inside_pupper(self, response):

     item = response.meta["item"]
     item['buildY']          = response.xpath('').extract_first().strip()
     item['on_m']            = response.xpath('').extract_first().strip()
     item['off_m']           = response.xpath('').extract_first().strip()
     yield item
```

Comment: I hope I can help others some day, the way you help me. Thank you!